# use output of command as grep argument

Tags: bash, process-substitution

I'm trying to use output of another command as grep argument (I think this feature is known as [Bash process substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html)). But the problem is that it does not work, grep did not find any entries

```
wakatana@ubuntu:~$ dpkg-query -Wf '${Installed-Size}\t${Package}\n' | sort -n | grep  <(uname -mrs | awk '{print $2}')
wakatana@ubuntu:~$
```

But when I first assign it to variable then it works:

```
wakatana@ubuntu:~$ pattern=$(uname -mrs | awk '{print $2}')
wakatana@ubuntu:~$ dpkg-query -Wf '${Installed-Size}\t${Package}\n' | sort -n | grep  $pattern
8222    linux-image-4.15.0-118-generic
12894   linux-headers-4.15.0-118-generic
64165   linux-modules-4.15.0-118-generic
165817  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-118-generic
```

Output of desired command is following

```
wakatana@ubuntu:~$ uname -mrs | awk '{print $2}'
4.15.0-118-generic
```

But when I echo result of process substitiution I get this:

```
wakatana@ubuntu:~$ echo  <(uname -mrs | awk '{print $2}')
/dev/fd/63
```

What I'm doing wrong?

OS info:

```
wakatana@ubuntu:~$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

wakatana@ubuntu:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic

wakatana@ubuntu:~$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 4.15.0-118-generic #119-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 8 12:30:01 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: You understand `uname -mrs | awk '{print $2}'` is the same a simply `uname -r`, right? If you like you can use *process substitution* to prove it to yourself, e.g. `diff <(uname -mrs | awk '{print $2}') <(uname -r)`

Answer (score 2):

You do not want to read from the stream associated with the output of command, you want to pass the whole result of a command as argument to another command. So you want:

```
dpkg-query -Wf '${Installed-Size}\t${Package}\n' | sort -n | grep "$(uname -mrs | awk '{print $2}')"
```

> What I'm doing wrong?

Well, I guess you wrongly expect *process substitution* to be substituted for the *content* of the output of a command, while it is being substituted with a single *filename* associated with the output of the command. To replace the command by the output produced by that command use *command substitution*. For further research I advise [bash manual process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution), [bash manual command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution).